# Angular UI-Grid and D3 graph in a row

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-ui-grid

I am wondering if any of you had any experience with injecting a graph into a ui-grid. What I am doing, is I have a row defined as follows:

```
  { name:'Column Name', cellTemplate: '<spark-line-chart values="grid.appScope.valuesStacked"></spark-line-chart>'}
```

Spark-line-chart directive is responsible for creating a D3 chart (actually, nvd3 to be precise). This creates svg graph.

Now, each time I am trying to sort my table, all of the values within the table get sorted, apart from the graphs. So far, I am mocking up data, and use one array of values for all of the graphs.

Anyone had similar issues, and knows the answer to this question?

Comment: I don't know ui-grid... but, apparently, ui-grid is swapping the contents of rows to order, but it can't to move the graphics row. Try to order directly on data, creating a filter:   data="myList | mySorter : selectedSorter" to force the update for all rows

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo, actually, when I added some other object-related data into the cell with graph, it sorts the data, but it leaves the graph out.

Comment: Can't you work around this with a user defined sorting function (https://github.com/timothyswt/ng-grid/wiki/Sorting-and-Filtering)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first which kind of Angular module for nvd3.js are you using?

If you use [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) you can check this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XESqEPwfXF3ulQkfuBOE

Pay attention that in your cell templates you must wrap the nvd3 graphic inside a `<DIV>` with `.ui-grid-cell-contents` CSS class:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
  <nvd3 options="row.entity.spark.options" data="row.entity.spark.data"></nvd3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats was it. Surrounding the graph with a div! High Five!

Comment: I am trying this with plotly.js cut could'nt do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315749/how-to-render-a-plotly-js-chart-in-a-angular-ui-grids-cell