# Angular uiGrid: D3 CellTemplate not sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, d3.js, svg

I am trying to show custom D3 cellTemplate in [UiGrid](http://ui-grid.info/) angular library and implement the sorting functionality. By following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809128/angular-ui-grid-and-d3-graph-in-a-row) I was able to implement it but used a custom directory instead of [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/). For sorting of column with custom template(here D3 elements) I am using sortingAlgorithm attribute of uiGrid. The problem is once the D3 is drawn for the whole grid, on sorting it is not updating.

**columDef:**

```
columnObj = {
                field: reportEvidenceHeaders[i],
                enableHiding: false,
                headerTooltip: true,
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><ui-grid-bar-chart data="row.entity.'+reportEvidenceHeaders[i]+'"></ui-grid-bar-chart></div>',
                sortingAlgorithm: uiGridViewSorting
            };
```

**uiGridViewSorting:**

```
var uiGridViewSorting = function(a, b, rowA, rowB, direction){
          a = Number(a.split("/")[0]);
          b = Number(b.split("/")[0]);
          if (a == b) return 0;
          if (a < b) return -1;
          return 1;
      };
```

ui-grid-bar-chart is the D3 directory.

**ui-grid-bar-chart:**

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    d3.select(element[0]).append("svg").height("100%").width("100%");
}
```

Here, I am appending the D3 on `element[0]`.

**Grid:**

[image]

The grid on first drawing looks fine.

But on sorting all the other columns are updated except the one containing the D3 elements.

**Plunker**: [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2oAF2H7aG8Y21BB4wpyL?p=preview)

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you provide an example Plunker?

Comment: @KScandrett My Bad, must have done it before, plz find the plunker link in the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

You would need to wrap the drawing of the graph in a `$watch` otherwise it doesn't know to redraw when the grid changes (more detailed explanation here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/743). This fixes scrolling, and sorting on the other columns, but by itself it won't fix sorting on the graph column:

```
scope.$watch('data', function() {
   drawUiGridBarChart(scope.data, scope.width);
});
```

Now to fix sorting on this column, `field` needs to point to `spark.data`

```
{ field: 'spark.data', // not field: 'uiGrid', 
    cellTemplate: '...
```

Updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/t281BcETvrLihSBAcWWo?p=preview

Comment: It seems to work! Even adding sortingAlgorithm instead of `field: 'spark.data'` enables sorting on d3 columns. Thanks.